How Does Serial Correlation Cause OLS to remain unbiased (even in cross -sectional data)
In order for the coefficient estimators to remain unbiased in OLS, the conditional expectation of errors given the regressors needs to be zero, $E(u_i |x_i )=0$.
However, if we have serial correlation in error terms, does this not bias the errors so that the conditional expectation of errors are no longer zero?
For example, if there is serial correlation in errors, such that we can fit the equation $u_i  = \phi_i *  u_j + \epsilon_i  $, won't this mean that $u_i$ is now biased to have a non-zero conditional mean (since $\epsilon_i $ is i.i.d)?
For example, if we have $x_i$ fixed, then changing $u_j$ impacts the conditional mean of $u_i$ given $x_i$?
Doesn't this violate the unbiasedness of OLS if serial correlation is breached?

Unbiased for what? One of the problems with OLS is that it is only unbiased in the sense of predicting the dependent variable. It is not unbiased for variability of the independent variable(s) as well. That is, it predicts a least error in y, not a best y=f(x). For the latter, regression in both x and y are needed.

I guess it also helps to think about the large number of samples scenario, where a mean zero, but autocorrelated error term, does not harm estimating the mean value. For a small number of samples I can see how the intuition tells you that the OLS estimator deviates from the true mean (but again this effect will vanish with more replications)

Does serial correlation exist for cross-sectional, nontemporal data?

Serial correlation is just one kind of dependence that can affect errors, although perhaps the leading kind for some groups. Others include spatial correlation and correlations or dependence that arise from block or group structure e.g. individuals within families or repeated observations for some individuals. In the last case time may be just implicit.

Unbiased here means unbiased over repeated draws of the data from the same generating process.
If you run the data generating process again you will get different $u_j$. They will be correlated in the sense that $u_{j-1}>0$ makes it more likely that $u_j>0$, but  the distribution of each $u_j$ over repeats is still mean-zero Normal.
So if $x_j$ is fixed, $E[u_j|x_j]=0$ for the expectation taken over repeats of the data generating process. That's enough to imply $E[\hat\beta|{\mathbf x}]=\beta$.  It doesn't imply that $\hat\beta x_j$ is a particularly good predictor; that's a different question.
